# C++ pointer compared with integer compile error

Tags: c++

My professor asks that we use the while function in c++ for a code we are writing. I keep returning the same error, so I wrote a simple simple code to understand the while loop. Still stuck at this part. It obviously isn't the end of my program, I just gets stuck at the while function. Any ideas?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void response (){
    cout<<" Continue loop function?\n";
    cout <<"y - yes\nn - no\n";
    char response='y';
    cin>> response;
    return;
}
int main (){
    response ();
    while (response=='y')
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: you have problem with variable scope: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_variable_scope.htm

Comment: +1 for writing a testcase to do your debugging. _Excellent_ move. I can't stress how important that is!! (shame your question is mislabelled as the problem has nothing to do with loops, but never mind)

Answer (score 2):

You can't access the function local `response` variable in `main()`.

In this line

```
 while (response=='y')
```

`response` is interpreted as the address of the `response()` function, compared to `'y'` which causes the error you see.

---

As others mentioned you should rather have something like this

```
char response (){
    cout<<" Continue loop function?\n";
    cout <<"y - yes\nn - no\n";
    char resp='y';
    cin >> resp;
    return resp;
}
int main (){
    while (response()=='y'); // << also note the semicolon here
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are several things wrong here. Your main function should probably look like this:

```
int main()
{
    while (response() == 'y')
    { //must have either an empty body or a semicolon here, 
      //otherwise our return statement will become the loop body!
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Also, your `response()` function should return the local variable `response` so its value can be returned to `main`. You can't use the `response` variable outside of the response function because of scope.

What your (erroneous) main function currently does is call the `response()` function and then try to compare your response function to the char literal `'y'`. However, this isn't comparing the value just returned from your function, it's comparing the memory address (pointer) of the function itself.

C++ allows you to have variables and functions with the same same, but it's usually a bad idea. You might want to give either your `response()` function or the `response` local variable a different name.

Comment: +1 for explaining where the actual warning message is coming from. Bonus points if you also point out the error(s) in `response()`. (the empty `return` with `void` as the type, and the horrid use of the function name as a local var).

Answer (score 1):

While is waiting for a boolean. In order to compare 'y' to response, you *must* change the return type from void to char :

```
char response (){
    cout<<" Continue loop function?\n";
    cout <<"y - yes\nn - no\n";
    char response='y';
    cin>> response;
    return response;
}
```